# Random number function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get a function that generate a random number, this is what I have so far:

```
getRandom :: Int -> Int -> Int
getRandom x y = do
    z <- randomRIO( x, y )
```

This code give me the following error:

```
The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
```

Now I understand this error, but I don't understand the solution.

I tried:

```
return z
```

But it doesn't work.

P.S. I'm very VERY new to Haskell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `do` block can't end in a binding. They desugar to something like

```
getRandom = randomRIO (x, y) >>= \z ->
```

which is obviously an error! If you want to just use the result of `randomRIO`

```
getRandom x y = randomRIO (x, y)
```

works fine. Additionally, if you just want a random number,

```
getRandom :: IO Integer
getRandom = randomIO
```

works.

Comment: I tried that, but I had the error: Couldn't match expected type 'Int' with actual type 'IO Int'

Comment: @nevero getRandom returns an `IO Int` since impure actions are left in the IO monad. I recommend reading the "IO" chapter of real world haskell